# waterproof activity watch to wear 24/7 with pedometer, heart rate monitor, auto sync data and with GPS to track running parkour

Tags: smart-device

I've never been interested in activity tracker, but I recently saw a Garmin watch that records your track and heart rate when you run and auto-sync on your computer when you get home and it got me interested. However, there is a lot of choices and I'm not sure there is one that fit my needs.

I'm looking for a watch to wear 24/7 that has the following specifications :
**Must-have specifications:**

- Display today's date and time on the home screen
- Display the number of steps I've made in my day on the home screen.
- Waterproof (Need to be able to take shower and bath with it)
- Quality wristband that holds up well. (It mustn't accidentally come undone by itself)
- Heart rate monitor that take measure automatically during my day
- The watch should automatically upload her data to my phone and/or PC without my intervention. (In a day, we more important thing to take care than having to synch a watch)
- At least 7 days of battery life (the longer the better). Otherwise, a watch with an extra rechargeable battery that can be swap easily could also suit me.

**Specifications I would really like but can live without :**

- Since I'm wearing it all the time, wristband shouldn't be made with a material that keeps odors easily. (E.G.: tissue that absorbs sweat)
- if the display isn't always on, there should be a way to activate the display without using the other hand. This because it is a bit cumbersome to have to use two hands to get the time.
- GPS that track my jogging races
- Seconds are displayed with the time
- Seconds are displayed with the time
- Waterproof (Would be nice if I could swim with it)
- I would prefer a small watch to a gigantic one because big watches tend to hook on everything.

---

Money isn't an issue and I'm willing to pay the extra bucks to get the GPS feature.

Is there a watch with all these specifications?
If not, which one come the closest to having all of these?

Comment: A watch with GPS turned On *will not* hold battery for more than a day or two maximum. And I don't think there's any good one with a swappable battery.

Comment: I only need the GPS feature when running, so it will be turned on less than 3 hours per week.